# Scan next mouse click (And use... with...)

Tags: java, events, click

Specifically, I'm trying to find out what makes popup boxes and drop down menus hide or continue showing depending on where you clicked in java.

I tried looking at the API but I didn't see what I was looking for.

1. How can I tell if the next click is a desired element or not? (hopefully I can work up from there)
2. Is there an easy way to get the properties of the next item clicked?

For instance, want to get the properties of `Object B` for a method of `Object A`. So when I click `Object A` I almost want an open method (not really of course) like

```
public void checkObject(Object object){
    System.out.println(Object.getName());
}
```

When I click `Object A` I could run something like

```
...scanNextMouseClick()
```

which would return the next item clicked then

```
...if('item clicked' != Object B) return;
```

I could do something like this to make sure I pass in the right type of parameter, if not, scanNextMouseClick would still be satisfied and my program would continue normally

```
...checkObject('item clicked') //to finally run the method.
```

Comment: I have gotten this effect but its not very neat, basically I put a mouse listener on Object A, when I click Object A it makes a static variable equal to A. I then added a mouse listener to Object B that says if the static variable is not null, run its method and pass in the static variable. It's pretty cringe worthy

Comment: Have you tried the mouseEventListener class

Comment: If its not an actual mouse listener then no, but I'll look it up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about swing then I think you are looking for a [focusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html).  Basically if your Object/component gains focus your focusListener performs the desired actions.  So if you click object A (if object A is say a JPanel), object A gains focus.  Having said that there is also an [actionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) class which listens for things like button clicks and such.

Comment: This helped A LOT! It didn't give me what I was looking for, but it's proven to be a great workaround.  Thank you!